# parameter won't change in a bash function

Tags: bash

For some reason the hello2 function won't change the b parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello1 {
  a=hello1A
}

function hello2 {
  while read -a line; do
    echo ${line[*]}
  done

  b=hello2B
}

a=mainA
b=mainB

echo $a
echo $b
hello1
echo some text | hello2
echo $a
echo $b
```

it prints:

```
mainA
mainB
some text
hello1A
mainB
```

but I want to change the b too:

```
mainA
mainB
some text
hello1A
hello2B <----- !
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `hello2` function is being invoked in a subshell and it only changes the value of the variable in the subshell.  If you want it to update, do not use a pipe.  You can do:

```
hello2 << EOF
some text
EOF
```

or (less portable)

```
hello2 <<< 'some text'
```

If "some text" is not literal, but the output of a command, you can also do:

```
hello2 << EOF
$( cmd )
EOF
```

or (less portable):

```
hello2 < <(cmd)
```

Another option is to keep the subshell alive for a longer duration and do:

```
echo some text | { hello2
echo $a
echo $b
}
```

but be aware that `$b` will revert back to its original value after the block ends.